# Bluetooth Dongle appearing, but not working in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: usb, bluetooth, 22.04, dongle

I've connected my Bluetooth dongle on Windows and it works fine on Windows. Yet, when I open Ubuntu (using dual-boot) it isn't working I tried answers on askUbuntu but nothing works.

Here are some commands I run and their outputs:

`lsusb`:

```
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 0a5c:5800 Broadcom Corp. BCM5880 Secure Applications Processor
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 04f2:1125 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd Asus Keyboard
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 0000:3825   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2802 Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. Laptop_Integrated_Webcam_FHD
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

`sudo dmesg | grep -i bluetooth`:

```
[  926.303205] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[  926.303245] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[  926.303247] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[  926.303254] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[  926.303256] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[  926.303262] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[  926.324145] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[  926.324156] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[  926.324160] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[  926.324163] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.
[  926.453334] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[  926.453340] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[  926.453344] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[  928.412762] Bluetooth: hci0: Opcode 0x c5a failed: -110
[  928.412775] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x0c5a tx timeout
```

`rfkill list`:

```
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: dell-wifi: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`hcitool dev`:

```
Devices:
```

`bluetoothctl`:

```
Agent registered
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
```

`grep . /sys/bus/usb/devices/[0-9]*/power/control`:

```
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1.5/power/control:auto
/sys/bus/usb/devices/1-1/power/control:auto
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.1/power/control:auto
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.2/power/control:on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.4/power/control:on
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1.8/power/control:auto
/sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/control:auto
```

I also tried this, I don't know why but I don't have permissions:
`sudo echo on > /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/control`:

```
bash: /sys/bus/usb/devices/2-1/power/control: Permission denied
```

`sudo hciconfig hci0 up`:

```
Can't init device hci0: Connection timed out (110)
```

I can provide more information if it is needed.

Comment: This may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/705772/bluetooth-not-working-debian

Comment: One thing you can try is from the Windows side. Make sure that when you shut down Windows and reboot to start Ubuntu that Windows is not in some kind of sleep or hibernate mode. Make sure it is truly and completely shut down.

Comment: @Jos This didn't work out as I don't understand what to do.. should I compile and run the c source code?

Comment: @David I made sure that Windows is completely shut down

Comment: Are you sure that this device works with Ubuntu? Not everything does. [  926.324145] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Unbranded CSR clone detected; adding workarounds and force-suspending once...
[  926.324156] Bluetooth: hci0: CSR: Couldn't suspend the device for our Barrot 8041a02 receive-issue workaround
[  926.324160] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Delete Stored Link Key command is advertised, but not supported.
[  926.324163] Bluetooth: hci0: HCI Set Event Filter command not supported.

Comment: A lot of not supported errors.

Comment: @MuhammadHussain No, I recommend either (1) upgrading to 22.10 or (2) waiting until you get the 5.19 kernel in 22.04, which apparently has been patched against this bug.

Comment: @Jos Thanks! I will wait

Comment: @David yeah I've checked the source code of patch given by Jos. It seems that Linux has blacklisted my device.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**This is a partial answer**

Background:

Until yesterday, I had been using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with a Plugable Broadcom-based Bluetooth dongle; it was working perfectly until I installed 22.04 LTS today, and now I am getting major problems very much along the lines that other 22.04 users have reported as well as the OP here.

I have tried everything that had been posted about work-arounds etc. to no avail. My dongle manufacturer (Plugable) had a download for the missing firmware file, so I tried that and still nothing.

What [partially] worked:

I went to the GitHub page for Broadcom, and there was an updated firmware there (handily in a Deb package file) that I downloaded, and it worked! You just need to copy the firmware file for your particular device/chipset into the /lib/firmware folder (mine was a folder within that firmware folder) and reboot. I could now pair the keyboard and mouse and no error messages about the firmware in DMESG, but the devices only work for about 10 minutes before I get timeout messages in DMESG from the devices, and eventually the Bluetooth locks up completely and needs a reboot.

I have read elsewhere that if you disable the Bluetooth power saving that will stop the timeouts and prevent the lock-up, so if someone knows how to do that we may have a complete solution. Again, sorry this is only a partial solution, but I think if the power saving issue can be fixed, and you get the same success as me from downloading a missing/outdated firmware from GitHub for your chipset, then this could be a fix. I hope this helps others who are suffering the same frustrations.

Example DMESG errors showing device timeouts and then the 'failed to resubmit' is when the adapter itself stops responding:

[  523.388039] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout

[  525.403978] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x2005 tx timeout

[  527.419850] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200b tx timeout

[  529.435976] Bluetooth: hci0: command 0x200c tx timeout

[  658.018739] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000005016cda9 failed to resubmit (113)

[  658.018774] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000006b705fe6 failed to resubmit (113)

[  658.019822] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000b1c332e8 failed to resubmit (113)

[ 1130.665552] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 00000000d82d69cd failed to resubmit (113)

[ 1130.665587] Bluetooth: hci0: urb 000000006b70d305 failed to resubmit (113)

Comment: A quick update... I decided to install the Bluez and Blueman packages. Having rebooted the machine and re-pairing with the Bluetooth Manager [touch wood!] I have a stable Bluetooth connection to both my keyboard and mouse. It struggled at first, and I have no idea if it made a difference, but I set PAN and DUN support to Blueman (originally set to NetworkManager) and everything suddenly seemed to settle down... I will let you know if this is a persistent fix.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).